# Error communicating with server in horde cpanel

Tags: cpanel, livechat, horde

Anybody can help me to solve,

> 'error communicating with server'

when I refresh the inbox message using Horde in **cpanel**? Was it because the live chat that I installed few hours before or was there something else that cause the problem ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not related with your chat software. Try to restart dovecot services on your server and check cPanel error logs if you are facing same issues.